# Why am I getting p-value 0.00000 in adfuller test?

Tags: python, time-series, arima, p-value

I am working with ARIMA. To make the data stationary I have transformed the data using log and then subtracted the values by using shift. When I tested again with a rolling mean and adfuller test. I am getting p-value to be 0.0000 why is it so?

My code:

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df =
Date        open         high         low        close       adjclose    Volume
2010-06-30  5.158000    6.084000    4.660000    4.766000    4.766000    85935500
2010-07-01  5.000000    5.184000    4.054000    4.392000    4.392000    41094000
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], infer_datetime_format=True)
df=df.set_index(['Date'])
def test_ad(values):
    mvm = values.rolling(window=12).mean()
    mvstd = values.rolling(window=12).std()
    orig = plt.plot(values,color='blue',label='org')
    mean = plt.plot(mvm,color='red',label='mvm')
    std=plt.plot(mvstd,color='black',label='mvstd')
    plt.legend(loc='best')
    plt.show(block=False)
    result=adfuller(values)
    print('ADF Statistic: %f' % result[0])
    print('p-value: %f' % result[1])
    print('Critical Values:')
    #labels = ['ADF Test Statistic','p-value','#Lags Used','Number of Observations Used']
    for key, value in result[4].items():
        print('\t%s: %.3f' % (key, value))
    if result[1] <= 0.05:
        print("Data is stationary")
    else:
        print("non-stationary ")

test_ad(df['Close'])
```

which gives:

```
ADF Statistic: 6.450459
p-value: 1.000000
Critical Values:
    1%: -3.433
    5%: -2.863
    10%: -2.567


df['log']=np.log(df["Close"])
df['close']=df['log']-df['log'].shift()
#df['close']=df['log'].diff()
test_ad(df['close'].dropna())
```

Which gives

```
ADF Statistic: -50.361617
    p-value: 0.000000
    Critical Values:
        1%: -3.433
        5%: -2.863
        10%: -2.567
```

The graph looks stationary and also the critical values got satisfied as you can see above.

Comment: Probably something wrong in your code, which you have not provided. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: You can see yourself that your ADF statistic is MUCH less than the critical value for 1%, therefore your p is probably just extremely small. If, as previously mentioned, you'd share your code and what libraries you're using to run the test it might be more clear why it prints out zeroes instead of an extremely small value.

Comment: @FredLarson Yes, Please check it again. I have updated with the code

Comment: @dm2 I have pasted the libraries which I used. Please check and advice what is going wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see yourself that your ADF statistic is MUCH less than the critical value for 1%, therefore your p is just extremely small.

What makes it confusing is that you are using `%f` to print out this value, which by default (i.e. without specifying the precision such as `%.2f` to include 2 decimals or `%.10f` to include 10 decimals) only includes 6 decimals after the point.

If you were to print the values in their entirety (such as `print('p-value: %s' % result[1])` where you treat your p-value as a string (thus no need to specify precision), or in an f-string `print(f'p-value: {result[1]}')`), you would see that you p-value is actually above 0 (although still very small).

Comment: Oh yes, I have removed and just passed  result=adfuller(df['close']). Getting p-value   4.064395147506604e-08,
Now is it correct? As the p-value should be around 0.09 to 0.05 right?

Comment: That's very unfortunate, but a chance for a lesson in how python string formatting works, as it just barely falls out of the range that you could see with '%f' (0.000000(your string finishes here)04).

Comment: @sirisha since your p-value is smaller than 0.05 you can reject null hypothesis that there's unit root (i.e. your data doesn't have unit root after transformation). 0.05 is standard, although you could go to 0.01 or 0.001 and still be happy because your p is MUCH less than that.

Comment: Yes, I got it. Many thanks and also I have one more doubt. We usually give shift(12) only for seasonal data why can't I give the same to non-seasonal data(trend)

Comment: 12 is used because, I assume, you've seen data that is monthly and spans years (so, seasons would be repeating every 12 months/datapoints). However seasonal part could be with 24 datapoints (hours in a day) or 7 points(days in a week) or whatever rate your data shows seasonality. AFAIK you should be able to plug in 12 into non-seasonal part, but beware of overdifferencing. For more info I suggest you check out: https://people.duke.edu/~rnau/411arim2.htm

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. But if consider the trend we have data on yearly basis. At that time can I apply shift(12)?

Comment: Honestly, I don't think I know this as thoroughly as to give you a good answer. I'd rather direct you to https://stats.stackexchange.com/